# hook_views_post_execute additional results not showing up

Tags: views, 6

I'm trying to conditionally add a few results to a view display, this seems to be working in that when I print the `$view` object after the changes it works as expected, each of the addition objects matches the format of the objects already contained in the views result set exactly.

Unfortunately when I visit a page with this view, even though the additions are present in the `view` object, they are not present in the rendered view. Is there something I'm missing? I've seen similar code snippets in several places that people say work..

```
function mymodule_views_post_execute(&$view) {

      if($view->name == "zohar_body_feed" && $view->args[0]==37) {
        global $user;


        $ir_chapters=db_query("SELECT ct.field_chapter_value AS chapter, n.nid, n.title FROM node AS n LEFT JOIN content_type_book_body AS ct ON n.nid=ct.nid LEFT JOIN term_node AS tn ON tn.nid=n.nid LEFT JOIN term_data AS td ON td.tid=tn.tid WHERE td.name='%s' AND n.type='zohar_body' ORDER BY ABS(chapter)",'Idra Raba');

        while($irc=db_fetch_object($ir_chapters)){
            $temp = new stdClass;
            $temp->nid=$irc->nid;
            $temp->node_data_field_chapter_field_chapter_value=$irc->chapter;
            $additions[]=$temp;
        }
        $results = array();
        foreach($view->result as $single_result) {
          if($single_result->node_data_field_chapter_field_chapter_value == 13) {
            foreach($additions as $addition){
                $results[] = $addition;
            }
          }
          $results[] = $single_result;
        }
        // replace the old result array
        $view->result = $results;
        if($user->uid==1) drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r($view,1).'</pre>');
      }
    }
```

I am using Views 2 on Drupal 6

Comment: is this a complete/accurate code cut and paste?  if so, I am not sure how it is working as you are setting `$view->result = $results;` which looks to be created only of your `$additions` if some chapter value is 13, and then `$new_result_array[]` is set to a "row" of the existing results, but is never included in your results when you `$view->result = $results;`.  So, I think some logic needs to be worked out as `views_post_execute()` and `views_pre_render()` all do work :)

Comment: That was a typo and is fixed, as I stated before the additions are being added to the results of the views accordingly, my problem isn't with logic it's with getting the results to render

Comment: Does your pager accommodate the appended results as well?

Comment: At the moment I'm just trying to get the results to display, I've set the "results per page" to the total number of rows that should be there after my additions are added and they still don't show up

Comment: Really? no answer yet?